# Spring Cloud Config - Multiple Composite Repositories?

Tags: spring-cloud-config

Is it possible configure Spring Cloud Config with multiple composite repositories?  Our setup uses multiple team-based repositories:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          repos:
            teamA:
              cloneOnStart: true
              pattern: teama-*
              searchPaths: '{profile}'
              uri: file:///etc/config/teama
            teamB:
              cloneOnStart: true
              pattern: teamb-*
              searchPaths: '{profile}'
              uri: file:///etc/config/teamb
```

We want each team to now pull from 2 different git repositories.  I think multiple Composite repositories (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#composite-environment-repositories) is what we want, but I can't figure out how to combine them, or if it is even possible.

## Clarification:

I want each team to pull configuration data from **two repos** instead of just the 1.  In pseudo code:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          repos:
            teamA:
              repo1:
                key1: repo1
                key2: repo1
              repo2:
                key1: repo2
                key2: repo2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case your can use composite configuration. Next configuration is working for me, client service is using properties from 2 repositories

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        composite:
        -
          type: git
          cloneOnStart: true
          uri: https://github.com/..../test-config
        -
          type: git
          cloneOnStart: true
          uri: https://github.com/..../test-config-2
```

You may need to configure 'searchPaths' for each for your needs. Profile should be composite (at least one of profiles)

Comment: I updated my question.  I'd like each team to get info from 2 repos, if possible.

Comment: Do you have team specific configuration for same projects in different repos and want to take it based on client profile ? Or you want just to use 2 git repos with different configurations for different projects ? What problem did you have during using composite configuration that you mentioned in the main question ?

Comment: The actual use case is this:  each team manages their own repo, but we want to manage some common properties in a common repo across all teams.  So we want teamA to read from teamA repo AND common repo.

Comment: modified the response. this sample configuration is working for me (just tried). One repository contains some properties, another different properties for the same service. Service needs all if them to start. If properties are the same precedence is determined by order of appearance in configuration file

Comment: i'm just now getting back to this. in your test configuration above, what rest url did you hit to get values from both repos. i get only a 404, but acuator endpoints show the config loaded correctly, so i'm definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: I used simple flat structure for demo. 

curl localhost:8888/myapp/development

{"name":"myapp","profiles":["development"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"https://github.com/nazar-mykolyshyn/test-config-2/myapp-development.properties","source":{"some.general.property":"general-test"}},{"name":"https://github.com/nazar-mykolyshyn/test-config/myapp-development.properties","source":{"some.property":"test"}}]}

Comment: @BigTexasDork - have you work around this issue? I'm looking for exactly same thing.

Comment: @dnf, I did not.  we ended going to a different solution