# How to get multiple brances in Spring Cloud Config?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I started to use spring cloud config and I have a branch for each client. There're configuration properties which are identical between the branches, and I would like not to duplicate them, but storing them in a single file.

Let's assume I have a branch named "my-branch" and it contains this file:

service.properties:

```
foo=123
```

In my master branch I have this file:

service.properties:

```
foo=456
bar=789
```

I want to query the label "my-branch" and to get this properties:

```
foo=123
bar=789
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

From what I investigated - it's not possible when you are using one repository.
You can achieve it by having composite environment and have common properties in another repo, but there is another limitation

> When using a composite environment, it is important that all repositories contain the same labels. If you have an environment similar to those in the preceding examples and you request configuration data with the master label but the Subversion repository does not contain a branch called master, the entire request fails.

See: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#composite-environment-repositories

In your case it's even more complicated because you are using branch per client.
So you will need to create a separate repo for common configuration with lot of branches for each client containing the same configuration.

In case you use one branch - it's easier and works fine, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51742129/9419680).