# Adding multiple repositories to Spring cloud config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I need to add two config repositories to my config server. But, it picks only one config repository. Can anyone please help me to fix this problem.

Config Server bootstrap.yml

```
server:
 port: 8899
spring:
 cloud:
  config:
   server:
    git:
      uri: https://github.com/pocuser9x/wednest-config-store
      search-paths:
        - 'wednest-config-store/*service'
    repos:
      uri: https://github.com/pocuser9x/secure-config-store
```

In https://github.com/pocuser9x/wednest-config-store I have below files

`event-service.yml`
`event-service-dev.yml`
`event-service-stg.yml`

These files are picking correctly.

In https://github.com/pocuser9x/secure-config-store I have below file
`event-service-prod.yml`
This file is not picking.

Comment: it seems it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737545/spring-cloud-config-multiple-composite-repositories

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the composite repo feature. It is documented [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#composite-environment-repositories).

For you, this would be something like:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        composite:
        -
          type: git
          uri: https://github.com/pocuser9x/wednest-config-store
          search-paths:
            'wednest-config-store/*service'

        -
          type: git
          uri: https://github.com/pocuser9x/secure-config-store
```

One note is that the documentation shows profile set as above, but I found a need to use "include" instead of "active". Include is additive.

```
  profiles:
    include: composite
```