# Configure Spring Cloud Config to read from multiple backends, but write to only one

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

all!

I'm trying to configure Spring Cloud Config to use two backends: a (read-only) local filesystem (native) backend, and a (read-write) JDBC backend.

I'm wondering if there's a means to tell the software via configuration that when constructing configuration sets it should read from both backends, but that any modifications should only go to one of the backends (JDBC, specifically).

Is this even possible?

Alternatively, in the client application we use a profile (named "modified") which is listed last in "application.profile", so all modifications go there. Is there any way to tell Cloud Config that said profile should only be stored in a specific backend?

I'm looking for something similar to (pseudo-config):

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "jdbc,native"
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          readOnly: false
          sql: "SELECT KEY, VALUE from ACM_CLOUDCONFIG where APPLICATION = ? and PROFILE = ? and LABEL = ?"
          order: 0
        native:
          readOnly: true
          searchLocations: "file:///blablabla...."
          order: 1
```

Or, alternatively (more pseudo-config):

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "jdbc,native"
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          profilePattern: "modified"
          sql: "SELECT KEY, VALUE from CONFIGURATION where APPLICATION = ? and PROFILE = ? and LABEL = ?"
          order: 0
        native:
          searchLocations: "file:///blablabla...."
          order: 1
```

Thoughts? Ideas? Is this even possible?

The goal is to be able to cluster many, many instances of Cloud Config and not have to worry about: a) filesystem corruption due to concurrent writes to the same filesystem (i.e. don't use *native* for writing), b) maintaining a centralized Git repo (which would also need to be deployed in HA in order to eliminate the SPOF, which means ***more*** work and ***more*** moving parts).

Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding multiple repositories to Spring cloud config server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443588/adding-multiple-repositories-to-spring-cloud-config-server)

Comment: Not quite. I had already read about composite repositories. What I don't quite know if it's possible is to restrict writing of configurations to only one backend from the multiple configured backends in the composite repository.